# How to match by regexp 3 and 4 bytes UTF-8

Tags: string, go, unicode, utf-8

I just want to find 3-byte character in Go using regexp.
But it panic with

> regexp: Compile(`\x{E29AA4}`): error parsing regexp: invalid escape
> sequence: `\x{E29AA4`

```
func get_words_from(text string) []string {
   words := regexp.MustCompile(`\x{E29AA4}`)
    return words.FindAllString(text, -1)
}

func main() {
    text := "One,ВАПОЛтлдо⚤two ыаплд⚤ы ыапю.ы./\tавthree!"
    fmt.Println(get_words_from(text))
}
```

You can try on [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/s6ZVX9Ejkc2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the UTF-8 byte sequence `E2 9A A4` with e.g. [`utf8.DecodeRune()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#DecodeRune) and use the resulting rune in the regexp:

```
func get_words_from(text string) []string {
    r, _ := utf8.DecodeRune([]byte{0xE2, 0x9A, 0xA4})
    words := regexp.MustCompile(string(r))
    return words.FindAllString(text, -1)
}
```

You may also simply [convert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) the byte slice to `string` (which interprets it as UTF-8 encoded bytes):

```
func get_words_from2(text string) []string {
    s := string([]byte{0xE2, 0x9A, 0xA4})
    words := regexp.MustCompile(s)
    return words.FindAllString(text, -1)
}
```

Or use the equivalent unicode code point (which is `0x26a4`) in the regexp string:

```
func get_words_from3(text string) []string {
    words := regexp.MustCompile("\u26a4")
    return words.FindAllString(text, -1)
}
```

Note that `"\u26a4"` is an interpreted `string` literal and will be unescaped by the Go compiler (not the [regexp](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/) package).

All examples return (try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jNVOSibADmb)):

```
[⚤ ⚤]
```

To filter out all runes that have 3 or more bytes in UTF-8, you may use a `for range` and [`utf8.RuneLen()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/utf8/#RuneLen):

```
text := "One,ВАПОЛтлдо⚤two ыаплд⚤ы ыапю.ы./\tавthree!"
fmt.Println(text)

var out []rune
for _, r := range text {
    if utf8.RuneLen(r) < 3 {
        out = append(out, r)
    }
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/1Rw2ng16OJ6)):

```
One,ВАПОЛтлдо⚤two ыаплд⚤ы ыапю.ы./  авthree!
One,ВАПОЛтлдоtwo ыаплды ыапю.ы./    авthree!
```

Or use [`strings.Map()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map), where you return `-1` for such runes, which then will be left out in the result:

```
out := strings.Map(func(r rune) rune {
    if utf8.RuneLen(r) < 3 {
        return r
    }
    return -1
}, text)
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

This outputs the same. Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/58bggRE0sOP).

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain, how to skip all UTF-8 4-bytes characters there? Extually, I need to have all strings starting ⚤ and ending any 4-byte UTF-8 character

Comment: Use `for range` over the string, which decodes its runes, and also reports the byte position. Whenever the byte position advances 4 bytes, skip that rune.

Comment: If the task is to find any character whose code point requires three bytes, or more than three bytes, to encode into UTF-8, it should not be hard to extend either method to cover that. Code points in the range U+0800 through U+FFFF require three bytes and anything from U+10000 up requires four. The Unicode code point range ends at U+10FFFF though theoretically UTF-8 could support a larger range, up to six encoded bytes.

Comment: @АлексейАверьянов Added examples how to filter out runes with 3 or more UTF-8 encoded bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Also I found that character ⚤ in regex can match by **\xE2\x9A\xA4** instead of wrong: **\x{E29AA4}**